# Photoshop CS6 Extended has OpenGL disabled?

Tags: graphics-card, adobe-photoshop

I've Googled everywhere and I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable OpenGL in PS CS6 E. I need to open an OBJ model but whenever I try, Photoshop gives me an error saying that I don't have OpenGL enabled. I wouldn't mind but there is no option to enable it!

I have Photoshop CS6 Extended 64-bit (fully updated) and my GPU is an R9 series so it definitely has OpenGL.

I am all out of ideas. Anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: You have the current driver for your graphics card installed? Photoshop uses automatic detection, so if its disabled, its specific to your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I have the latest GPU driver installed (it is a beta driver, however)

Comment: Why are you using the beta driver.  Go back to the stable driver

Comment: The beta drivers apparently make things run faster. I'll roll back and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to use the beta driver but never got round to installing it. I'm still on the recommended version (14.12). I found my OpenGL version, if that helps (6.14.10.13283).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have something to do with Photoshop CS6 as upgrading to CC fixed the issue.